# Node.JS: stream HTTP client request body?

Tags: http, node.js, stream, client

I want to create a two-way stream between a Node.JS client and a Node.JS server, via an HTTP connection. But it seems that the server's `request` event is not called until the client calls `req.end()`. How can I establish a two-way communication? Do I need to use separate requests?

Clarification: My expectation was that it was possible for

1. The client to send the request header,
2. The server to send the response header, and
3. The server and client to send bytes whenever they want.

Edit: OK, here is the summary of the options:

- **TCP sockets on a separate port:** This is good if you don't mind opening a separate port, and then modifying previous use of HTTP (request path and headers, and response headers) to use the stream instead. (I declined this option.)
- **Separate HTTP requests,** ending the request every time you need to flush. Managing the state would be done in the application, because now an ended connection will no longer represent an ended session. (In the short term, I will use this option.)
- **Socket.IO** (which is an implementation of **WebSockets** + reverse compatibility): This option is very appealing, but you need to add the Socket.IO layer to be in front of the HTTP layer. Socket.IO would pass through all HTTP requests, but WebSocket requests would be handled differently. (In the long term, I will use this option, but I will have to modify my front-end to permit this.)

  As I understand it, the Node.JS `http` library will not allow me to send a response header, unless the client has already completed (or at least substantially began) sending the request body. This I suppose is for good reason, so this third option can also be titled **Add a layer in front of the `http` library.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really looking for a 2-way communication system, HTTP is not really the correct protocol.. The whole idea is that it's stateless and handled 1 request at a time. There's exceptions to this rule, but those are really stretching what HTTP is supposed to do, and could be considered hacks.

It sounds like you should be using something like [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)

Comment: In this case, all I want is something that is compatible with Node.JS, not at all something for the browsers to use. I think Socket.IO is overkill but I could be wrong.

Comment: Socket.io works on node too, and you will probably love it once you try it. It's quite easy as well. I started with socket.io for a prototype, meaning to roll my own once the application developed further; but I never did..

Comment: HTTP does sound like a bad idea.. if you do want to avoid socket.io, use pure TCP sockets.

Comment: See my edit. I have listed the options as I see them. Feel free to add a comment if you think I should expand on or modify them.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey: It would also be option to just open a secondary port. You should be able to run Socket.IO and your HTTP logic separately. Thanks for accepting the answer, I'm very curious what you end up with going. I do hope, whatever you do, don't go with HTTP :) Eventually you can make it work, but it will always remain a hack.

Comment: Since this particular case does not require much in the way of streams, I just used a couple separated HTTP requests. See the edit I referred to *"In the short term, I will use this option."*. In the long term I do indeed plan *"to modify my front-end to permit [Socket.IO]"*. On the other hand, thanks for the separate port suggestion.